# Creating a map in XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon, xquery-3.0

I am trying to create a hash-map/ key-value pair like structure in xquery. I am aware a map like structure exists in xquery: http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map/

and even found documentation in Saxon: http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/map/

However I am both unsure how to create a map or use it.

Here's my code so far:

```
declare namespace map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
let $a := map:map()
```

But I get an error:

```
Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named
  {http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map}map()
```

So how exactly do I use maps in xquery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is in XSLT 3.0 and XQuery 3.1 and has been through a few iterations as the working drafts have evolved. The current syntax (supported in Saxon 9.7) allows

```
map{}
```

for an empty map

```
map{'a':1, 'b':2}
```

for a map with a known number of entries (both the keys and the values can be arbitrary expressions), and

```
map:merge(for $x in //emp return map{$x!name : $x!@salary})
```

for a map with a statically-unknown number of entries.

Comment: This seems to be on the right track but now I get the following error: `To use XPath 3.1 syntax, you must configure the XPath parser to handle it`. How do I do this

Comment: Depends on the interface you are using: command line? s9api API? XQJ?

Comment: I think I managed that issue but what does: `$x!name : $x!@salary` part mean. I never seen this syntax with the "!". What does it mean?

Comment: The "!" operator is new in XPath 3.0. A!B means roughly the same as `for $a in A return B`, except that B is evaluated with $a as the context item. So another way of thinking about it is that it's the same as A/B, except that A doesn't have to consist only of nodes, and there is no sorting into document order. I have got into the habit of using it in situations like this where "/" would do just as well.